# Update security db and then access new role in xdmp:permission

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using an xdmp:invoke call to create a new role in the security database.  As options to the invoke call, I have specified the following options:

```
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <database>{ xdmp:security-database() }</database>
  <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
  <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
  <prevent-deadlocks>false</prevent-deadlocks>
</options>
```

My thought is that this would execute in a separate transaction, and then I would be able to access the change in the code following this call.  But when I make a all to xdmp:permission() using the name of the role I just created, I get a Role Does Not Exist error.

Is there anyway to resolve this?

**Update**

The following snippet works.  So I will troubleshoot more to see if there is some other issue in my more complex code.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sec = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"
  at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";

let $create_role :=
  xdmp:invoke-function(
    function() {
      sec:create-role(
        'sec_test',
        'Security Test Role',
        (),
        (),
        ()
      )
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{xdmp:security-database()}</database>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
      <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
    </options>
  )

return xdmp:permission('sec_test', 'read')
```

**2nd Update**

It appears that if the function I am calling to do the create-role is in another xqy file, then it fails with the role not found error.  For example, I have the following module in security-util.xqy.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace asu = "http://ir.abbvie.com/marklogic/authorization/lib/security-util";

import module namespace sec = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"
  at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare function asu:create-role-2(
  $role_name as xs:string
)
{
  xdmp:invoke-function(
    function() {
      sec:create-role(
        $role_name,
        "Role auto created by AbbVie authorization library.",
        (),
        (),
        ()
      )
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{ xdmp:security-database() }</database>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
      <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
    </options>
  )
};
```

And if I call it from the query console:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace asu =    "http://ir.abbvie.com/marklogic/authorization/lib/security-util"
  at "security-util.xqy";

asu:create-role-2('sec_test7'), xdmp:permission('sec_test7', 'read')
```

That will error out, where as the following just works fine:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sec = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security"
  at "/MarkLogic/security.xqy";  

declare function local:create-role(
  $role_name as xs:string
)
{
  xdmp:invoke-function(
    function() {
      sec:create-role(
        $role_name,
        "Security Test Role",
        (),
        (),
        ()
      )
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">

      <database>{ xdmp:security-database() }</database>
      <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
      <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
    </options>
  )
};

local:create-role('sec_test8'), xdmp:permission('sec_test8', 'read')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider getting the permission via invoke-function as well. You are creating the role in a separate transaction, so the current request could be looking at the state of the database before that commit. This is part of the MVCC model that MarkLogic uses to support non-locking query-mode.

It could also be that lazy evaluation is disturbing your code. Sub-expressions in a sequence (e.g. anything comma-separated) can get executed in parallel. Use let-return from FLWOR to enforce order..

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Geert. Putting the xdmp:permission() call in an invoke-function resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified it has actually created the role? If it's not actually being created, try changing the transaction-mode to "update-auto-commit". I suspect your transction to add the role isn't actually getting committed.

Also, if all you're doing is creating a role, it might be simpler to use something like the following so that you don't have to define a separate .xqy for a small bit of code.

```
xdmp:invoke-function(
  function() { sec:create-role(...) },
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{xdmp:security-database()}</database>
    <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
    <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
  </options>)
```

Comment: That is kind of what I am doing.  The role is being created because after I get the error, if I go to the admin interface, I can see the role created there.  I actually have a call to xdmp:commit() after the call to sec:create-role.

Comment: I changed the options to match what you suggested... but, same error. The call to create the role is in a different .xqy file, but that should be affecting anything, right?

Comment: I updated my question with a simple test snippet, which works fine.. so there must be some thing wrong with my code.